# @ViewChild returns undefined reference in child component form

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have a form in the parent component that transfers data to the child component as an input property and the child component has a form that reads this data and prepopulates its form with this data as a way to edit the userprofile. In the line where I try to set the input fields with the transferred data, chrome returns a console error stating that it can't read setValue property of undefined. what could be the wrong with the code?

**Here is that code:**

```
this.eForm.setValue({
        firstname: this.employee.user.firstname,
        lastname: this.employee.user.lastname,
        email: this.employee.user.email
      });
```

**Child component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from 'src/app/services/data.service';
import { NgForm, ControlContainer } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-manager-view-employee-profile',
  templateUrl: './manager-view-employee-profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./manager-view-employee-profile.component.css'],
  viewProviders: [ { provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm } ]
})
export class ManagerViewEmployeeProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('f', {static: false}) eForm: NgForm;

  @Input() employee: any;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    console.log(this.eForm);
    console.log(this.employee.user.firstname);
this.eForm.setValue({
    firstname: this.employee.user.firstname,
    lastname: this.employee.user.lastname,
    email: this.employee.user.email
  });
  }

  onSubmit(f: NgForm){



    }
}
```

**Child Component template:**

```
<form class="col-md-6" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group mb-2">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <div class="input-group-text">First Name</div>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroup" name="firstname" ngModel required>
            <span *ngIf="f.form.controls.firstname?.touched && !f.form.controls.firstname?.valid" style="color: red;">A is required.</span>
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group mb-2">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <div class="input-group-text">Last Name</div>
              </div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroup" name="lastname" ngModel required>
              <span *ngIf="f.form.controls.lastname?.touched && !f.form.controls.lastname?.valid" style="color: red;">A is required.</span>
            </div>

          </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group mb-2">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <div class="input-group-text">Email</div>
              </div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroup" name="email" ngModel required>
              <span *ngIf="f.form.controls.email?.touched && !f.form.controls.email?.valid" style="color: red;">An email is required.</span>
            </div>

          </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!f.form.valid">Search</button>
      </form>
```

Comment: Change from `{ static: false }` to `{ static: true }`..! See [here in the docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) about the `@ViewChild`..!

Comment: @RohitSharma This works. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
// query results available in ngOnInit
@ViewChild('f', {static: true}) eForm: NgForm;
```

Or

```
ngAfterViewInit() {

this.eForm.setValue({
    firstname: this.employee.user.firstname,
    lastname: this.employee.user.lastname,
    email: this.employee.user.email
  });

}
```

https://angular.io/guide/static-query-migration